# MySQL Binary Type Usage example

Tags: mysql

I have a 20 character

```
'id' CHAR(20) NOT NULL CHARACTER SET latin1,
```

Can I use the Binary data type:

1) in order to save space

2) speed up searches, as the id is the primary index?

If yes, how? Do i need to convert my id to hex?

Comment: instead of SET latin1 put SET binary

Comment: isn't 'id' BINARY(3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL's `BINARY` data type, like `CHAR`, holds fixed-length strings.  You still have to specify the width of the column, e.g. `BINARY(20)`.  The only difference is that MySQL treats the data within the column as raw bytes rather than encoded text.

Assuming that you maintain the same data within the column, but merely change the column's datatype to `BINARY(20)` instead of `CHAR(20) CHARACTER SET latin1`, then:

1. > in order to save space

   No.  Since `latin1` is a one-byte character set, both data types will occupy 20 bytes per field.  See [Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/storage-requirements.html).
2. > speed up searches, as the id is the primary index?

   Not really.  The only difference will arise through the additional time required to perform comparisons under your chosen collation.  If this is truly of concern (and it very much should not be), you could simply use the `latin1_bin` collation instead.
3. Should the column actually contain text data, you will no longer benefit from MySQL's automatic transcoding and application of collations: so operations depending on such behaviour will either need to explicitly ask that of MySQL (losing the benefits of indexing) or else perform it within the application layer (could prove very expensive indeed).

Are you actually suffering from a shortage of storage space, or slow searches?  If so, perhaps you should profile your storage/queries accordingly in order to determine where resources are being hogged; otherwise, I am reminded of Knuth's maxim: *premature optimisation is the root of all evil*.

If after investigating you discover that your problem does indeed lie with the length of your primary key, you might instead consider using a surrogate value: e.g. MySQL's `SERIAL` data type.

Comment: I don't have any issue with space. The table should be able to hold 500m rows. For that reason I need the fastest possible option. I CAN'T, change the primary key. My primary key MUST be small letters and numbers (so, 36 possible characters) and 20 characters in length. What's the best way to make this faster?

Comment: Because of the length of the key, I can store it as 2 bigints, somehow. Is this better than a char(20)?

Comment: @user3054967: To make *what* faster?  Besides "searches", your question has not specified any particular operation.  It's pretty difficult to advise how to make "*this*" faster without knowing what "*this*" is.  As for whether 2 `BIGINT` columns is "*better*" than a `CHAR(20)` column, it's again impossible to say without knowing what on Earth you're trying to achieve: but I would note that it has the advantage of only needing 16 bytes instead of 20 (although 36^20 < 2^(8*13), so your data would fit in 13 bytes).

Comment: Database engine is InnoDB. I perform about 10-20/sec updates if the row exists, inserts if not. Also I read data, about 10-20/sec. The column sizes are small. I know optimization is not a simple matter, but I believe it should be simple to tell witch is faster: char(20), binary(20), 2 usinged long ints, used as primary index.

Comment: @user3054967: The reality is that the data type will have relatively little bearing.  So the most succinct answer that I can give is that you're asking the wrong question.  If you are suffering from slow performance, *profile* your queries and post the output (together with the schema, the slow queries and the `EXPLAIN` plan) in a new question.

Comment: @user3054967: Then one presumes that 500 million rows is sufficiently far into the future for it to not be a concern you need expend resource on right now?  It'd probably be wise to focus on more current problems.